# sharepoint remote event receiver itemDeleting event not firing

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver

I have written a remote event receiver to fire when item is deleting in a docmentlibarary. but itemDleting event is not firing.But itemAdded and ItemDeleted events are working ok.

in remote event receiver file

```
public void ProcessOneWayEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {


            if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.ItemDeleting)
            {
                using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
                {
                    if (clientContext != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            DeleteDocuments(properties);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) { }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

in appeventreceiver file

```
 public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();
            if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.AppInstalled)
            {
                using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, false))
                {
                    if (clientContext != null)
                    {
                        //Get reference to the host web list with name Feedback
                        var documentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pre Meeting Docs");


                        clientContext.Load(documentsList);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                        string remoteUrl = "https://xxxxx.net/Services/RemoteEventReceiver1.svc";



                        //Create the remote event receiver definition for deletion
                        EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation deleteEventReceiver = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation()
                        {
                            EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemDeleting,
                            ReceiverAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
                            ReceiverName = "RemoteEventReceiver1",
                            ReceiverClass = "RemoteEventReceiver1",
                            ReceiverUrl = remoteUrl,
                            SequenceNumber = 15001
                        };


                        //Add the remote event receiver to the host web list

                        documentsList.EventReceivers.Add(deleteEventReceiver);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.AppUninstalling)
            {
                using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, false))
                {
                    var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pre Meeting Docs");

                    clientContext.Load(list);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    EventReceiverDefinitionCollection erdc = list.EventReceivers;
                    clientContext.Load(erdc);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    List<EventReceiverDefinition> toDelete = new List<EventReceiverDefinition>();
                    foreach (EventReceiverDefinition erd in erdc)
                    {
                        if (erd.ReceiverName == "RemoteEventReceiver1")
                        {
                            toDelete.Add(erd);
                        }
                    }
                    //Delete the remote event receiver from the list, when the app gets uninstalled
                    foreach (EventReceiverDefinition item in toDelete)
                    {
                        item.DeleteObject();
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

in elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListTemplateId="3101"> 
    <Receiver>
      <Name>RemoteEventReceiver1ItemDeleting</Name>
      <Type>ItemDeleting</Type>
      <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      <Url>~remoteAppUrl/Services/RemoteEventReceiver1.svc</Url>
    </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use any of the "-ing" events, then write your codes in **ProcessEvent()**.

**ProcessEvent()**

It handles "Before" events and returns an object to SharePoint that reports on whether it should cancel the current process or terminate it.

If you want to use any of the "-ing" events, then write your codes in ProcessEvent().

**ProcessOneWayEvent()**

It handles "After" events. It runs asynchronously and does not return anything to SharePoint.

If you are using any code which is to be run after the “-ed” event, then write your codes in ProcessOneWayEvent().

Check the article here: [Difference Between Process Event() And Process One Way Event() In Event Receiver](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/difference-between-process-event-and-process-one-way-event-in-event-receiver)

Comment: you save me lot of my time. thanks.